# Can't find class drawable

Tags: java, class, import, drawable

I'm trying to use `java.awt` for graphics, which is what I used to use, but I'm getting a weird error.

Netbeans says it can't find the Drawable class. I would check all my old code from when I used to use Java but it's on a dead laptop. I have the JDK and Netbeans Java SE downloaded, and as far as I can remember I never had to download anything else. Any idea on what the problem is?

Here's the code:

```
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Ball implements Drawable {
    }
```

Btw the error is "cannot find symbol, symbol: class Drawable", not that I haven't implemented the draw method yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Interface/Class Drawable in awt:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html

Comment: Haha you're right there's not, apparently my memory is betraying me.  I'm sure I used to extend JComponent and use paint...

Answer (score 0):

for that you will have to import `jcommon.jar` jar into your project.

Or if you are making android project then you can find that class in the package `android.graphics.drawable`.

Comment: there's a drawable in jogl, maybe he wants that.

Comment: I did a little work on android apps before I stopped and I think I got that mixed up with JComponent and its paint method.  Thanks for the help.